# Fullscreen jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I wrote a jQuery plugin, which set the DOM size to the window size. When i resize the window i want to follow it, but it not work. Here is the code:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fullScreen = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "width" : $(window).width(),
            "height" : $(window).height()
        })
        $(window).resize(function() {
            $(this).css({
                "width" : $(window).width(),
                "height" : $(window).height()
            })
        })
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Is a plugin needed? CSS: `.full-screen { display: block; height: 100%; left: 0; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; }` JS: `$(...).addClass('full-screen');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the $(this) in the windows resize event is refering to window. Try:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fullScreen = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        $(this).css({
            "width" : $(window).width(),
            "height" : $(window).height()
        })
        $(window).resize(function() {
            self.css({
                "width" : $(window).width(),
                "height" : $(window).height()
            })
        })
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```